# Array curly braces

Tags: arrays, brackets

Please, how to make these two curly brackets in an array?

[image]

[image]

**Edit:**

I just took liberty to glue the two half images above.

[image]

Comment: Do you also want the two asymmetric moustaches? ;o)

Comment: ^_^ Sorry, I need the two curly brackets without moustaches.

Comment: I meant the broken outer parentheses.

Comment: These are parts of the array parentheses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools, bigstrut}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{pmatrix}
    \bigstrut[t] 0 & & & & & 0 \\[-0.5ex]
     \vdots & & & \raisebox{0.35ex}[0pt][0pt]{$ \begin{rcases}0\\[-1ex] \vdots within{0} \\[-0.75ex]0\end{rcases}\left\lfloor\frac{i}{2}\right\rfloor $} &
                   & \vdots \\
    0 & & & & & 0 \\
     \vdots \\[-1.5ex]
     \vdots \\
    0 & & & & & \raisebox{0.35ex}[0pt]{$\left\lfloor\frac{i}{2}\right\rfloor \begin{cases}0\\[-1ex] \vdots within{0} \\[-0.75ex]0\end{cases}\hspace{-1em}$}
  \end{pmatrix} \]


\end{document}
```

[image]

To have the 0s in the last column aligned, you can   use the `pmatrix*` environment (defined by `mathtools`)  with option`[r]`, as mentioned by @Mico. However this will have the effect that *all* columns will be right-aligned, which might be unwanted (for instance a 0 in the second column, last row, would require a left alignment), or use `\llap` for this specific element:

```
\[ \begin{pmatrix}
    \bigstrut[t] 0 & & & & & 0 \\[-0.5ex]
      \vdots & & & \raisebox{0.35ex}[0pt][0pt]{$ \begin{rcases}0\\[-1ex] \vdotswithin{0} \\[-0.75ex]0\end{rcases}\left\lfloor\frac{i}{2}\right\rfloor $} &
                    & \vdots \\
    0 & & & & \qquad & 0 \\
      \vdots \\[-1.5ex]
      \vdots \\
    0 & & & & \qquad & \raisebox{0.35ex}[0pt]{\llap{$\left\lfloor\frac{i}{2}\right\rfloor \begin{cases}0\\[-1ex] \vdotswithin{0} \\[-0.75ex]0\end{cases}$\hspace{-1.4em}}}
  \end{pmatrix} \]
```

[image]

Comment: In the third column. The zeros should be under each other.

Comment: @Ahmed - Just change `\begin{pmatrix}` to `\begin{pmatrix*}[r]`, `\end{pmatrix}` to `\end{pmatrix*}`, and (while you're at it) both instances of `\vdots within` to `\vdotswithin`.

Comment: @Ahmed: I hadn't seen your updated image.  Mico's solution is the right solution if you want all columns to be right-aligned

Answer (score 5):

Among other options, nested arrays could be used for building this big array. The curly braces can be written as `\Biggl\{` and `\Biggr\}`, both from amsmath package. For more than three rows, `\Biggl` and `\Biggr` will not be large enough and one will resort to `\left` and `\right`. In the latter case, you need to prepend/append all other arrays with `\left.`/`\right.` to fix horizontal alignment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\begin{document}

\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1.5em}
\[\left(
\begin{array}{@{}lr@{}} 
    \begin{array}{@{}cc@{}} 
      0  &  0  \\
      \vdots  &  \vdots  \\
      0  &  0 
    \end{array}\Biggr\}\left\lceil\frac i2\right\rceil
    &
    \begin{array}{@{}c@{}} 
      0  \\  \vdots  \\  0       
    \end{array}
    \\  &  \\
    \begin{array}{@{}c@{}} 
      \vdots \\  \\  0       
    \end{array} & \left\lfloor\frac i2\right\rfloor 
    \Biggl\{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} 
      0  \\  \vdots  \\  0 
    \end{array}
\end{array}
\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Another possibility:

```
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2em}
\newcommand{\lbrce}{\smash{\left.\rule{0pt}{25pt}\right\}}} 
\newcommand{\rbrce}{\smash{\left\{\rule{0pt}{25pt}\right.}} 
\newcommand{\sdots}{\smash{\vdots}}    
\[
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0      & 0 & 0 \\
  \sdots & \sdots\makebox[0pt][l]{$\lbrce\left\lceil\frac i2\right\rceil$} & \sdots \\
  0      & 0 &   \\
         &   & 0 \\
         &   & \makebox[0pt][r]{$\left\lfloor\frac i2\right\rfloor\rbrce$}\sdots \\
  0      &   & 0
 \end{pmatrix}
\]
```

> [image]

Comment: Although the _inner_ braces don't enclose completely their content as in Bernard's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible implementation without unnecessary spaces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
% local command
\newcommand{\zerocol}{\begin{matrix}0\\\vdots\\0\end{matrix}}
\begin{pmatrix}
\zerocol & & \zerocol
 & \kern-\nulldelimiterspace\kern-2\arraycolsep
   \left.\vphantom{\zerocol}\right\rbrace\left\lceil\frac{i}{2}\right\rceil
 & \zerocol
\\
\zerocol & & &
  \left\lfloor\frac{i}{2}\right\rfloor\left\lbrace\vphantom{\zerocol}\right.
  \kern-\nulldelimiterspace\kern-2\arraycolsep
& \zerocol
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]